# Find minimum total server downtime

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

You have an array that represents a line of servers by their "Down-time cost". You can only access servers at either end of the line (i.e You can only get the **first** server or the **last** server).

The order at which a server is picked is multiplied with it's downtime and added to a "total downtime cost".

Design a program to find the least total downtime cost.

For example, for the array:

`[5, 3, 6, 2, 1, 4]`

the least total downtime is:

`5*1 + 4*2 + 3*3 + 6*4 + 2*5 + 1*6 = 62`

This is the code that I use for getting this result:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] serverDowntimes = {5, 3, 6, 2, 1, 4};

    int start = 0;
    int end = serverDowntimes.length - 1;
    long totalCost = 0;
    int serverNumber = 1;
    while(start <= end){
        if(serverDowntimes[start] >= serverDowntimes[end]){
            totalCost += serverNumber * serverDowntimes[start];
            start++; //Increment start (i.e. First server in line was recovered)
        }else{
            totalCost += serverNumber * serverDowntimes[end];
            end--; //Decrement end (i.e. Last server in line was recovered)
        }
        serverNumber++;
    }
    System.out.println(totalCost);
}
```

However my code fails when I have this array:

`[5, 3, 1, 8, 2, 4]`

For this array my code outputs:

`76 (5*1 + 4*2 + 3*3 + 2*4 + 8*5 + 1*6)`

However the better answer should be:

`73 (4*1 + 2*2 + 8*3 + 5*4 + 3*5 + 1*6)`

How do I modify my code so that it also works with the arrays similar to:

`[5, 3, 1, 8, 2, 4]`

Comment: It's not clear what is meant by "You can get the first server or the last server only" - that suggests you can only access the first and last elements of the array, which is mad.

Comment: It seems that the highest number shall be chosen for the next cost calculation; the highest number among the first and the last. If that is the requirement, then the output is correct and your assumption is wrong. If that is not the requirement, then please explain it much more detailed.

Comment: why 6 is chosen after 4 ?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose It is not a requirement to pick the highest among first and last. You would generally want to move towards the server with the highest downtime first. So that the "most expensive" server is recovered asap.

Comment: Uhm, and the array elements represent a server's downtime, right? Which simply means: Select the highest number first. Really, if this is not correct, then it is very unclear. Please update your post and make it more clear. I am voting to close ...

Comment: @Mohit Because in the first round 5 is picked so now the line is: [3, 6, 2, 1, 4] So then 4 is picked and the line looks like: [3, 6, 2, 1]. Then 3 is picked so now the line looks like [6, 2, 1]. And now finally 6 is picked because only at this point 6 at one of the ends of the line. Therefore 6 is after 4

Comment: The algorithm you are using is an example of [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm). It doesn't take into consideration more than one value, so it generates a suboptimal solution. You could use a brute-force method (checking every possible combination) or find an algorithm that's smarter.

Comment: And according to this algorithm, let's look at `[5,3,1,8,2,4]`: First the 5 is chosen and we have `[3,1,8,2,4]`. Here we take out the 4 which results in `[3,1,8,2]`. We now take the 3 and get `[1,8,2]`. Then the 2 (getting `[1,8]`), and finally the 8 and then the 1. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose My post clearly states "You can only access servers at either end of the line(i.e You can get the first server or the last server only)" So you can not simply "select the highest". You have to get to the highest by clearing the line. Carefully look at the examples I have in the post.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes you did mention first and last and you also understand the idea of prioritizing the highest number which means you are on a right track. Given that, I do not understand what you are confused about?

Comment: Ah, yes. I see it now! You have to get to the highest value as fast as possible, But that seems not to be enough. Other high values should also be accessed first. But if you can acces only the last or first of the remaining values, you cannot see the higher values inside. You have to consider a brute force method that actually evaluates all possible paths. Maybe a recursion or a stack will help.

Comment: Additionally, I now see, that the lowest minimum for your example is 61 (and not 62). The combination is 5,3,6,4,21.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Awesome! Your answer for example 1 is even better. This has me convinced that a brute force method would be a better approach.

Comment: @mkierc I am running your solution through various test-cases. I will definitely accept your answer once it passes all of my test-cases. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote brute-force algorithm that tests every possible solution and picks the best.

For following problem set:

`[5, 3, 1, 8, 2, 4]`

It generates solution of:

`lowest cost: 72, with combination: [5, 4, 2, 8, 3, 1]`

Which we can prove by calculating:

`5*1 + 4*2 + 2*3 + 8*4 + 3*5 + 1*6 = 72`

Here's the solver:

```
import java.util.*;

class ServersProblemSolver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] serverDowntimes = {5, 3, 1, 8, 2, 4};

        int totalCost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        List<Integer> bestCombination = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, serverDowntimes.length); i++) {
            int temporaryCost = 0;
            int combination = i;
            int start = 0;
            int end = serverDowntimes.length - 1;
            List<Integer> temporaryCombination = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int k = 0; k < serverDowntimes.length; k++) {
                if (combination % 2 == 1) {
                    temporaryCost += (k + 1) * serverDowntimes[start];
                    temporaryCombination.add(serverDowntimes[start]);
                    start++;
                } else {
                    temporaryCost += (k + 1) * serverDowntimes[end];
                    temporaryCombination.add(serverDowntimes[end]);
                    end--;
                }
                combination /= 2;
            }

            System.out.println("combination " + i + ": " + temporaryCombination + ", cost : " + temporaryCost);

            if (temporaryCost < totalCost) {
                totalCost = temporaryCost;
                bestCombination = temporaryCombination;
            } else {
                temporaryCombination.clear();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("lowest cost: " + totalCost + ", with combination: " + bestCombination);
    }
}
```

---

#### How does it work?

- Take every binary combination between `0` and `2 ^ N`, where `N` is the size of your array.
- Pick a server from `start` or `end` according to succesive binary digit (whether it's `0` or `1`)

  - `101` will take `start`, `end`, `start`
  - `000` will take `end`, `end`, `end`
  - `110` will take `end`, `start`, `start`
  - etc.
- After calculating the result of current combination, check if it's better than the previous best, and if so, save it.